# Menu doesn't open

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4

I've made a new project in Angular then created my structure:

```
src
-- app
--- app.component.html
---- modules
----- private
----- dashboard
------- dashboard.component.html
------ page1
------ page2
---- public
--- security
--- shared
-- assets
```

in my **index.html** i have

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Dashboard</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/dist/css/prj.css">
</head>

<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini sidebar-collapse">
<div class="wrapper">
  <app-root></app-root>
</div>

<script src="./assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/dist/js/prj.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

in my **app.component.html** i have

```
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In my **dashboard.component.html** i have

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <app-breadcrumb></app-breadcrumb>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

When it's done like this, my menu in the sidebar don't open (show submenu).
But if i move the code from the file **dashboard.component.html** to **app.component.html** everything is working fine, so i don't get what is going wrong, probably something with jquery/css path but i can't find the solution, any tips ?

Thank you!

Comment: You should use an Angular version of Bootstrap rather than the bare library, which allows data-driven behavior.

Comment: If there was a problem with the jQuery path you'd see console errors. Do you?

Comment: @isherwood there's no error message in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths are a pain in the ... well.. something proverbial

Skip the ./ (dot-slash) part and always refer to your files from root starting with just / (slash)

In that case it doesn't matter what the current path is : you're always referring to the root + path

In your case I'd go for this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Dashboard</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/dist/css/prj.css">
</head>

<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini sidebar-collapse">
<div class="wrapper">
  <app-root></app-root>
</div>

<script src="/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/dist/js/prj.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried this before but it doesn't solve my problem. 
But i'll keep your advise in mind for the './' !